# How can I sort all index of objects in array

Tags: ios8

I am using this line of code; my array contains name, email and phone no. This code only sorts namewise, but I want email and phone no with name. How can I do this that my array separeNamesByLetters contains email and phone with name?

```
 NSMutableSet *firstCharacters = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:0];
    for( NSString*string in [ tableDataArray valueForKey:@"name"] ){
        [firstCharacters addObject:[[string substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]];
    }
    NSArray *allLetters = [[firstCharacters allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    int indexLetter = 0;
    separeNamesByLetters = [NSMutableArray new];



    for (NSString *letter in allLetters) {
        NSMutableDictionary*userBegeinsWith = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [userBegeinsWith setObject:letter forKey:@"letter" ];
        NSMutableArray *groupNameByLetters = [NSMutableArray new];

        NSString *compareLetter1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", allLetters[indexLetter]];
        for (NSString*friendName in[ tableDataArray valueForKey:@"name"]) {
            NSString *compareLetter2 = [[friendName substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];

            if ( [compareLetter1 isEqualToString:compareLetter2] ) {
                [groupNameByLetters addObject:friendName];
            }
        }
        indexLetter++;
        [userBegeinsWith setObject:groupNameByLetters forKey:@"list"];
        [separeNamesByLetters addObject: userBegeinsWith];
    }



    NSLog(@"%@", separeNamesByLetters);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using NSSortDescriptors? See the following example:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Doe, John", @"name", @"3361231234", @"phone", @"johndoe@email.com", @"email", nil];
[array addObject:dict];

dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Doe, Jane", @"name", @"9191234532", @"phone", @"janedoe@email.com", @"email", nil];
[array addObject:dict];

NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor =
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
  initWithKey:@"name"
  ascending:YES
  selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSSortDescriptor *phoneDescriptor =
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
  initWithKey:@"phone"
  ascending:YES
  selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSSortDescriptor *emailDescriptor =
[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
 initWithKey:@"email"
 ascending:YES
 selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameDescriptor, phoneDescriptor, emailDescriptor, nil];
NSArray * sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: your code is working fine but my question is that how i do with this array that section A has contact begin with A and so on.. how i can use it in section tableview

Answer (score 0):

When I do this, I create a new NSArray of NSDictionaries. The NSDictionary has two properties: sectionTitle and records. The sectionTitle holds the first-letter of the field you are searching on. The records contain the actual objects that begin with that sectionTitle.

Add this sectionTitle method to your model class. I usually do this in an Extension to the actual model class.

```
- (NSString *)sectionTitle:(NSString*)sortByProperty {

    NSString *propertyValue;

    if ([sortByProperty isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
        if (self.name == nil) return @"";
        propertyValue = self.name;
    } else if ([sortByProperty isEqualToString:@"email"]) {
        if (self.email == nil) return @"";
        propertyValue = self.phone;
    } else if ([sortByProperty isEqualToString:@"phone"]) {
        if (self.phone == nil) return @"";
        propertyValue = phone
    }

    NSString *tmp;
    if ([propertyValue length] > 0) {
        tmp = [propertyValue substringToIndex:1];
    } else {
        return @"";
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

This should be quicker than iterating through your array each time you refresh your tableView.

Next, iterate through these sectionTitles, filter your array, and add the filtered results to the records attribute of the dictionary:

```
- (NSMutableArray*)sortedArrayForUITableView:(NSMutableArray *)tableDataArray sortBy:(NSString*)sortByProperty {

    NSArray *tmp = [tableDataArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.sectionTitle"];
    NSArray *allLetters = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[tmp sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES]]]];

    NSMutableArray *tree = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSString *sectionTitle in allLetters) {

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.sectionTitle == %@", sectionTitle];
        NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[tableDataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
        NSArray *sortedArray = [tmpArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortByProperty ascending:YES]]];

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:sectionTitle, @"sectionTitle", sortedArray, @"records", nil];

        [tree addObject:dict];

    }
    return tree;
}
```

You will need to implement several UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [self.tree count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self.tree objectAtIndex:section]];
    NSArray *tmp = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"records"]];

    return [tmp count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[self.tree objectAtIndex:section]];
    return [dict objectForKey:@"sectionTitle"];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.allLetters;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return index;
}
```

Lastly, you will build your cell in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. Hope that helps.

Comment: hi.. mrbcg where i call this method - (NSMutableArray*)sortedArrayForUITableView:(NSMutableArray *)tableDataArray sortBy:(NSString*)sortByProperty {

Comment: and also where i call this method  - (NSString *)sectionTitle:(NSString*)sortByProperty {

Comment: i am unable to use this code please mention here where i can use it